# Website footer overlapping content

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with trying to get my footer to stay at the bottom. It's overlapping my content. Can you please help me? Thank you!

Link to HTML and CSS: http://codepen.io/jacobrdoty/pen/EPzmXr

```
#footer {
width:100%;
height:40px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
```

Comment: looking at your [codepen](http://codepen.io/jacobrdoty/pen/EPzmXr); are you **sure** that it is good representation of your website's styling and structure?

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
#footer { 
width:100%; 
height:40px;
position:fixed; 
bottom:0px; 
left:0px; 
}
```

Comment: I see this, but this makes it fixed. Any idea with relative?

Comment: You said you wanted it to stay at the bottom. If you don't want it fixed, just remove `position`, `bottom`, and `left`. Default `position` is `relative`. You'll also need to change your other elements to not be positioned absolute, because they're messing up the flow of the page.